# How to perform argument parsing in C?

Tags: linux-kernel, c, utilities, glibc

I am trying to write an utility that runs on linux Operating System. I am planning to develop it using C. I have lots of doubts striking me. I would like to ask some of it.

**Questions 1:**

How can I parse argument using C?

In python, we  have a module that makes it easy to parse arguments. Is there any similar or better way to perform the same using C?

ie: In linux, pressing '`tab`' auto fills the command. I would like to have similar functionalities in my utility. How would I program that using C?

**Question 2:**

While developing utilities(of any kind), Is it better to use the functions provided by the linux kernel or continue with those in `libc`?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I parse argument using C?

POSIX provides [getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) for parsing command-line arguments.

On Linux systems, the GNU C library provides an extended [getopt_long](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) function that allows for long named parameters in addition to the single-character flags supported by plain getopt.

> In linux, pressing 'tab' auto fills the command. I would like to have similar functionalities in my utility. How would I program that using C?

If you want your program to show a prompt of its own and provide line editing and context-sensitive autocompletion, look into [readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline).

> While developing utilities(of any kind), Is it better to use the functions provided by the linux kernel or continue with those in libc?

Libc is what provides you with syscall bindings anyway (unless you go to ridiculous extremes to avoid that, which will generally involve writing your own assembler code and buys you nothing but headaches).

In general, use the highest-level services that will allow you to do what you need to, unless you have *clear, specific and measured* performance reasons telling you otherwise.